# Consider the Bernoulli (p) distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the Bernoulli (p) distribution. Show that if $p > \frac{1}{2}$, the median is 1; if $p < \frac{1}{2}$, the median is zero, and if   $ p= \frac{1}{2},$ every $0 \leq x \leq 1$ is a median.

The definition of median is a random variable $P\{X \leq x \} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $P\{X \geq x \} \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

I tried looking for examples but I couldn't find any. Can anyone give me a push? I was thinking of assuming $p=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Well, take your $p=\frac 34$.  Then $P(X≤1)=1$ is certainly greater than $\frac 12$ and $P(X≥1)=P(X=1)=\frac 34>\frac 12$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Taking your example, if $p = \frac{3}{4}$ then $P(X=1) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $P(X=0) = \frac{1}{4}$. Median is $x$ such that $P\{X \leq x \} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $P\{X \geq x \} \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

If $x<1$ then $P\{X \leq x \} = P\{X < 1 \} = P\{X = 0 \} = \frac{1}{4}.$ So when $x=1$ we have $P\{X \leq 1 \} = 1$ and $P\{X \geq 1 \} = \frac{3}{4}$. Thus the median is $x=1$.

Now generalising this argument for any $p>0.5$.

If $x<1$ then $P\{X \leq x \} = P\{X < 1 \} = P\{X = 0 \} = 1-p < 0.5.$ So when $x=1$ we have $P\{X \leq 1 \} = 1$ and $P\{X \geq 1 \} = p > 0.5$. Thus the median is $x=1$.

Similarly work out for other cases.

Comment: I'm bad at generalizing things, but would it be somethinng like $P(X=1)>\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X=0)< \frac{1}{2}$.?

Comment: Yes, exactly for the case of $p > 0.5$. @Killercamin

Comment: So for the case of $p<\frac{1}{2}$. Would it be similar such as $P(X=1)<\frac{1}{2}$ then P(X=0) > \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: For any $x>0$, yes that's what you will get @Killercamin